# page redirect is working but the functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have four tabs with four edit button in all the tabs. if i click on the edit button it should redirect to the first tab .now the redirect is working fine but the inside functionality not triggered.

**HTML:**

```
<button id='HTML_EditQuote' onclick = 'EditQuote()' type="button" style="display:none;">EDIT</button>
```

**jquery:**

```
if ((cart_cont_sct == 'Quote Summary' || cart_cont_sct == 'Transaction Info' || cart_cont_sct == 'Revisions' || cart_cont_sct == 'Approvals' || cart_cont_sct == 'Documents') && QtStatus =='Preparing Revision')
   {  
    $("button#HTML_EditQuote").css('display', 'block');
   }
```

**Edit click function:**

```
function EditQuote()
   {
      var path = window.location.pathname;
      var cartpg=path.split("/").reverse()[0];
       if(cartpg!="Cart.aspx" && cartpg!="")
        {      
          location.href='\Cart.aspx?TabId=5'
          $("#HTML_EditQuote").trigger("click");     
        }      
        -------codes-----------
  }
```

Comment: Because the `location.href` redirect therefore the `$("#HTML_EditQuote").trigger("click");` command does not run!

Comment: it should be redirect and then the function should be trigger

Comment: I understand it but this way not working

Comment: can i know which is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script to use localStorage:

```
   if( window.localStorage.getItem('quoteClicked') === '1' ){
       $("#HTML_EditQuote").trigger("click");
   }

   function EditQuote()
   {
       var path = window.location.pathname;
       var cartpg=path.split("/").reverse()[0];
       if(cartpg!="Cart.aspx" && cartpg!="")
       {      
           window.localStorage.setItem('quoteClicked', '1');
           location.href='\Cart.aspx?TabId=5'
                
       }
       else {
           window.localStorage.setItem('quoteClicked', '0');
       }      
       /*-------codes-----------*/
   }
```

Comment: Thanks adam, but on page loading my changes are there but after page loaded its gone.